# The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create new const like this but i got error

```
export const fakeExpertOperationalEdited: ExpertOperational = {
    comment: 'comment',
    useSlots: true,
    workingDay: new ExpertWorkingDay[] = [
        {
            weekDay: 'MONDAY',
            operationalAM: {
                fixed: false,
                startTime: '11:00',
                endTime: '12:00'
            },
            operationalPM: {
                fixed: false,
                startTime: '11:00',
                endTime: '12:00'
            }
        }

    ],
    workSpeedSurvey: '10'
};

export class ExpertWorkingDay {
  constructor(
    public weekDay: WeekDays,
    public operationalAM: ExpertWorkingHours,
    public operationalPM: ExpertWorkingHours
  ) { }
}
```

This is my error

**The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access**

Any one got idea where i am going wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be? The value of workingDay makes no sense.

Comment: workingDay: Array(2)
0: ExpertWorkingDay {weekDay: "MONDAY", operationalAM: ExpertWorkingHours, operationalPM: ExpertWorkingHours}
1: ExpertWorkingDay {weekDay: "TUESDAY", operationalAM: ExpertWorkingHours

Comment: Your code doesn't mention Tuesday at all, so that expectation doesn't seem reasonable. It's not clear to me what you expected `new ExpertWorkingDay[]` to be or why you're trying to assign to it inside an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
workingDay: new ExpertWorkingDay[] = [ ... ]
```

just try

```
workingDay:  [ ... ]
```

because you can not create an array with new. New is for instantiating classes.

So it would be

```
 workingDay: [
     new ExportWorkingDay( ... ),
     new ExportWorkingDay( ... )
 ]
```

Comment: I am expecting result to be
workingDay: Array(2) 0: ExpertWorkingDay {weekDay: "MONDAY", operationalAM: ExpertWorkingHours, operationalPM: ExpertWorkingHours} 1: ExpertWorkingDay {weekDay: "TUESDAY", operationalAM: ExpertWorkingHours

Comment: extended answer -> the objects need to be created one by one. The question is if a class is necessary here (will you need methods on them) or would a interface be better?